# Curl multi returns "couldn't connect to server" when number of easy handles are large

Tags: curl, libcurl

I try to download a map mosaic containing +100k images with curl multi but I get random "couldn't connect to server". If I limit the number of new handles to each call to curl_multi_perform to be less than 512 it works but this is not how it is supposed to be?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>
#include <curl/curl.h>

std::mutex total_size_mutex;

static size_t response_callback(void *data, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userdata)
{
  size_t real_size = size * nmemb;
  size_t *total_size = (size_t *)userdata;
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(total_size_mutex);
  *total_size += real_size;
  return real_size;
}

// C++ main function
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  std::string access_token(argv[1]);
  access_token = std::string("Authorization: Bearer ") + access_token;
  struct curl_slist *chunk = NULL;
  chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, access_token.c_str());
  chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "Connection: close");
  
  int sets = 50;
  int cols = 3;
  int rows = 795;
  int still_running = 1; /* keep number of running handles */
  size_t total_size = 0;
  
  curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
  CURLMcode mc;
  CURLMsg *msg; /* for picking up messages with the transfer status */
  int msgs_left; /* how many messages are left */
  CURL **m_handles = new CURL*[sets * cols * rows];
  CURLM *multi_handle = curl_multi_init();
  int numfds = 0;
  for(int d = 0; d < sets; ++d){
    for(int m = 0; m < cols; ++m){
        for(int n = 0; n < rows; ++n){
          char path[256];
          snprintf(path, 256, argv[2], d, m, n);
          m_handles[d * cols * rows + m * rows + n] = curl_easy_init();
          if(!m_handles[d * cols * rows + m * rows + n]) std::cout << "curl_easy_init() failed for " << d << m << n << std::endl;
          curl_easy_setopt(m_handles[d * cols * rows + m * rows + n], CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, response_callback);
          curl_easy_setopt(m_handles[d * cols * rows + m * rows + n], CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void *)&total_size);
          curl_easy_setopt(m_handles[d * cols * rows + m * rows + n], CURLOPT_URL, path);
          curl_easy_setopt(m_handles[d * cols * rows + m * rows + n], CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, chunk);
          curl_easy_setopt(m_handles[d * cols * rows + m * rows + n], CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0);
          mc = curl_multi_add_handle(multi_handle, m_handles[d * cols * rows + m * rows + n]);
          if(mc != CURLM_OK) std::cout << "curl_multi_add_handle: " << curl_multi_strerror(mc) << std::endl;
          if(++numfds > 512){  // THIS IS NEEDED TO AVOID COULDN'T CONNECT TO SERVER !!!
            numfds = 0;
            mc = curl_multi_perform(multi_handle, &still_running);
          }
      }
    }
  }
  
  do {
    mc = curl_multi_perform(multi_handle, &still_running);
    if(mc != CURLM_OK){
      std::cout << "curl_multi_perform: " << curl_multi_strerror(mc) << std::endl;
      break;
    }

    mc = curl_multi_poll(multi_handle, NULL, 0, 100, &numfds);
    if(mc != CURLM_OK) std::cout << "curl_multi_perform: " << curl_multi_strerror(mc) << std::endl;

    std::cout << still_running << "\t" << total_size << "\t" << numfds << std::endl;

    if(mc != CURLM_OK) break;
  } while(still_running);


    while((msg = curl_multi_info_read(multi_handle, &msgs_left))) {
      if(msg->msg == CURLMSG_DONE) {
        int d, m, n;
        for(d = 0; d < sets; ++d){
          for(m = 0; m < cols; ++m){
            for(n = 0; n < rows; ++n){
              if(msg->easy_handle == m_handles[d * cols * rows + m * rows + n]) break;
            }
            if(msg->easy_handle == m_handles[d * cols * rows + m * rows + n]) break;
          }
          if(msg->easy_handle == m_handles[d * cols * rows + m * rows + n]) break;
        }

        if(msg->data.result){ 
          std::cout << d << "\t" << m << "\t" << n << "\t" << curl_easy_strerror(msg->data.result) << std::endl;
        }

      }
    }
  

  
  // Cleanup
  if(chunk){
    curl_slist_free_all(chunk);
  }
  for(int d = 0; d < sets; ++d){
    for(int m = 0; m < cols; ++m){
      for(int n = 0; n < rows; ++n){
        curl_multi_remove_handle(multi_handle, m_handles[d * cols * rows + m * rows + n]);
        curl_easy_cleanup(m_handles[d * cols * rows + m * rows + n]);
      }
    }
  }
  curl_multi_cleanup(multi_handle);
  curl_global_cleanup();
  delete[] m_handles;

  std::cout << "Total size downloaded: " << total_size << std::endl;
  
 
  return 0;
}
```

Without the lines

```
          if(++numfds > 512){  // THIS IS NEEDED TO AVOID COULDN'T CONNECT TO SERVER !!!
            numfds = 0;
            mc = curl_multi_perform(multi_handle, &still_running);
          }
```

I get a lot of "couldn't connect to server"